# Trying to appending list items to dynamic id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to add "children" list items to "family" lists. I have a first form to create the families and a second form which is a select box to create the children and add them to a selected family from the select box. The Ol's ids are dynamically created and the drop down's options dynamically created.

When an option is created, the values are incremented every time a family and option is made.

My plan is to reference the OL families by using the options, basically corresponding to the family by the time it is created.

For example when I make a family1, there will be an option created with that family1 with a value 1, and when family2 is created, an option 2 is created with a value of 2.

I'm trying to append children to the family but I have no idea how to reference the OL's ids

this is what I have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $(document).on('click', "#submit", function () {
        var str = ' '
        var family = document.getElementById('famname').value;
        $('#family input[type = text],input[type = text],input[type = text],input[type = text]').each(function () {
            str = str + $(this).val() + '  ';
            $(this).val('');
        });

        $("<ol>", {
            text: str,
            id: "family+" + i
        }).appendTo("#container").append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn2',
            text: 'Remove'
        }));

        $('#select').append($('<option />', {
            text: family,
            value: i
        }));

        i++;
    });

    // Append items functions
    $(document).on('click', "#submit2", function () {
        var child = prompt("Please enter the child you want to add");
        var e = document.getElementById("select");
        var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        $('<li>', {
            text: child
        }).appendTo( ? ? ? ).append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn',
            text: 'Remove'
        }))
    });

    //delete items functions 
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });

    // delete the list
    $(document).on('click', '.btn2', function () {
        $(this).parent().next().remove();
        $(this).closest('ol').remove();
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>



<form id ="family" method = "post" target="_parent">
Enter Family Name <input type = "text" name = "famname" id = "famname" > <br>
Enter Address <input type = "text" name = "address"> <br>
Enter Father's name <input type = "text" name = "dad"> <br>
Enter Mother's name<input type = "text" name = "mom"> <br>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<p>Select Which family you want to add a child to</p>
<form id = "child">
<select id ="select">
</select>
<input id="submit2" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>

<div id  = "container">

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tip and help are appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/Jnewguy/4LVTz/

Comment: Please post only the relevant piece(s) of code in your question. This is way to long to read (unless you pay us ;)

Comment: A fiddle will be helping! can you do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jnewguy/4LVTz/  here you go guys sorry just wanted to give all info that'll help =x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;

    var $famname = $('#famname');
    var $finputs = $('#family input[type = text]').not('#famname');
    $(document).on('click', "#submit", function () {
        var family = $famname.val();

        var $ol = $("<ol>", {
            id: "family-" + i
        }).appendTo("#container");

        $('<li />', {
            text: family
        }).append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn2',
            text: 'Remove'
        })).appendTo($ol);

        $finputs.each(function () {
            $('<li />', {
                text: this.value
            }).appendTo($ol);
            $(this).val('');
        });


        $('#select').append($('<option />', {
            text: family,
            value: i
        }));

        i++;
    });

    // Append items functions
    var $select = $('#select')
    $(document).on('click', "#submit2", function () {
        var child = prompt("Please enter the child you want to add");

        $('<li>', {
            text: child
        }).appendTo('#family-' + $select.val()).append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn',
            text: 'Remove'
        }))
    });

    //delete items functions 

    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });

    // delete the list

    $(document).on('click', '.btn2', function () {
        $(this).parent().next().remove();
        $(this).closest('ol').remove();

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6q748/)